# Numbering an array of equations

Tags: equations, arrays

I want to do this thing in an equation array mode. Exactly same in the figure.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! :) It looks like you forgot to add the figure you refer to and also a minimal working example. Maybe you can edit your question to add both?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Please don't replicate this abomination of math. Even minimums are spelled wrong.

Comment: regarding equation numbers, if you're using `amsmath`, look into `subequations`.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
\min z_1  = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{l} \tilde{c}_{ijk}x_{ijk} \\
\min z_2  = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{l} \tilde{t}_{ijk}y_{ijk} \\
\intertext{subject to,}
 \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{K=1}^l x_{ijk} \leq a_i, \qquad i=1,2,3,\dots,m, \\
 \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{K=1}^l x_{ijk} \geq b_i, \qquad j=1,2,3,\dots,n, \\
 \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ijk} \leq e_k, \qquad k=1,2,3,\dots,l, \\
\intertext{$x_{ijk} \geq 0$, and}
y_{ijk} = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if}\ x_{ijk} > 0; \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
for all $i, j, k$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You, but my problem is about the "equation number", which not solved yet.

Comment: @Mr.AmritDas I've updated my answer with `subequations` environment which solves the problem with equation numbers.